# What is the difference between e.printStackTrace(System.out) and e.printStackTrace()?

Tags: java, exception, logging, log4j

2 Questions:

1. What is the difference between e.printStackTrace(System.out) and e.printStackTrace() ?
2. Is it safe (from the production point of view) to replace e.printStackTrace(System.out) and e.printStackTrace() with log4j using logger.error("", e) if i want to print out the stack trace in my log file?

Comment: `Throwable.printStackTrace()` prints to `System.err`.

Comment: And what does Throwable.printStackTrace(System.out) do? @JohannesKuhn

Comment: Did you read the API docs? It prints it to the supplied non-default output, `System.out`, instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. `e.printStackTrace()` is same as `e.printStackTrace(System.err). So, it prints to standard error.` e.printStackTrace(System.out)` prints to system out.
2. You should never do `e.printStackTrace()`, `System.out.print()`, `System.err.print()` on a production code. You should always use logger methods, and configure your logger.